Trying to add a variable to apex class
I Have the following APEX class to send an email with an attachment from flow
and I have a requirement to make the email field a variable from the flow.
public class sendAnEmailSele {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Selement send' description='sends an email')
  public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(List<id> listofQuoteHeader){   
    Map<Id, Selement__c> quotesMap =  new Map<Id, Selement__c>([
      SELECT id FROM Selement__c WHERE Id IN :listofQuoteHeader
    ]);
    List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMessages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(Id QuoteHeaderid :listofQuoteHeader){
      PageReference pref= page.Selement;
      pref.getParameters().put('id',(Id)QuoteHeaderid);
      pref.setRedirect(true);
      Attachment attachment = new Attachment();      
      Blob b;
      if ( Test.isRunningTest() ){
        b = blob.valueOf('hello world');
      } else {
        b = pref.getContentAsPDF();
      }
      attachment.Body = b;
      attachment.Name = Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') + ' ' + 'Sele' + '.pdf';
      attachment.IsPrivate = false;
      attachment.ParentId = QuoteHeaderid;
      attachment.Name='Sign.png';
      attachments.add(attachment);
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach= new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
      attach.setFileName('AttachmentEmailFile.pdf');
      attach.setBody(b);
      semail.setSubject('Sele print ' + Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'));
      String[] emailIds= new String[]{'test@test.com'}; 
    
      semail.setToAddresses(emailIds);
      semail.setPlainTextBody('Selement');
      semail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attach});
      emailMessages.add(semail);
    }
    insert attachments;
    if ( Test.isRunningTest() == FALSE ){
      Messaging.sendEmail(emailMessages);
    }
  }
}


Add a custom class:
public class Request {
  @InvocableVariable public Id quoteId;
  @INvocableVariable public String email;
}

Then, change the method to use the new parameter:
public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(Request[] requests){   

Finally, change the rest of your code to use the new variable, as appropriate.
The first part of your code should look like this:
public class sendAnEmailSele {
  public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable public Id quoteId;
    @INvocableVariable public String email;
  }
  @InvocableMethod(label='Selement send' description='sends an email')
  public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(Request[] requests){   
    // ... rest of code
  }
}

Edit: Complete example.
public class sendAnEmailSele {
  public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable public Id quoteId;
    @INvocableVariable public String email;
  }
  @InvocableMethod(label='Selement send' description='sends an email')
  public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(Request[] requests){
    // Populate the original array of Ids
    Id[] listofQuoteHeader = new Id[0];
    for(Request request: requests) {
        listofQuoteHeader.add(record.quoteId);
    }
    Map<Id, Selement__c> quotesMap =  new Map<Id, Selement__c>([
      SELECT id FROM Selement__c WHERE Id IN :listofQuoteHeader
    ]);
    List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailMessages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    // Use requests instead of quote Id
    for(Request request: requests){
      // Use the original parameter name to avoid refactoring
      Id QuoteHeaderid = request.quoteId;
      PageReference pref= page.Selement;
      pref.getParameters().put('id',QuoteHeaderid);
      pref.setRedirect(true);
      Attachment attachment = new Attachment();      
      Blob b;
      if ( Test.isRunningTest() ){
        b = blob.valueOf('hello world');
      } else {
        b = pref.getContentAsPDF();
      }
      attachment.Body = b;
      attachment.Name = Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') + ' ' + 'Sele' + '.pdf';
      attachment.IsPrivate = false;
      attachment.ParentId = QuoteHeaderid;
      attachment.Name='Sign.png';
      attachments.add(attachment);
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach= new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
      attach.setFileName('AttachmentEmailFile.pdf');
      attach.setBody(b);
      semail.setSubject('Sele print ' + Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'));
      // Now we can get the email address
      String[] emailIds= new String[]{request.email};
      semail.setToAddresses(emailIds);
      semail.setPlainTextBody('Selement');
      semail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{attach});
      emailMessages.add(semail);
    }
    insert attachments;
    if ( Test.isRunningTest() == FALSE ){
      Messaging.sendEmail(emailMessages);
    }
  }
}


When I am adding the code you gave me, it is telling me "InvocableMethod is not allowed on classes"

@SamBiz This error means the @InvocableMethod is on the wrong line. Make sure it precedes the function sendEmailWithAttachment.

I am struggling with that for hours, can you please guide me of where to put each code

@SamBiz I've edited my answer to show how your class should start.

Thank you so much,
I have edited the code, but now it tells me that Variable does not exist: quoteId

@SamBiz Yes, you'll need to edit your code to use the Request parameter.

It looks like I need to define the Request parameter, how is that done?

@SamBiz Thanks for your contribution (totally wasn't necessary, but VERY appreciated at the moment). I've refactored your code to avoid any compilation errors, but I haven't tested it.
